# How I can make required params in Intents with and check if allRequiredParamsPresent = true webhooks

Tags: node.js, firebase, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm making a agent in dialogflow. I want to make my parameters in a Intent to be required, like I have it in the dialogflow ui console, with the respective PROMPTS, but write it in a webhook throw firebase in a nodejs enviroment to be available to include Basic cards, carousel.

```
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

app.intent(INTENT_NAME, (conv, {parameters1, parameters2, 
parameters3, parameters4, parameters5, parameters6, parameters7}) => {

});
```

This is the response:

```
{
  "responseId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "text",
    "action": "action_name",
    "parameters": {
      "parameters1": [
        "responsetext1"
      ],
      "parameters2": [
        "responsetext2"
      ],
      "parameters3": [
        "responsetext3",
        "responsetext3"
      ],
      "parameters4": [
        "responsetext4"
      ],
      "parameters5": [
        "responsetext5"
      ],
      "parameters6": [
        "responsetext6"
      ],
      "parameters7": [
        "responsetext7"
      ]
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "response text",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "response text"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a list of all the required params in your webhook, then check all these params has values or not.
If they are null, reset the context and send a response asking for values of remaining params.

Comment: Sure I was thinking in something like that however I was trying to find a Method from the  `const  dialogflow  = require('actions-on-google')`
or similar